# How to avoid general Swagger Warnings?

Tags: spring, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springfox

i am going to validate my swagger (v2)  documentation in  http://editor.swagger.io/#/ but i got follow warning message.

> {
>              "generalSwaggerWarnings": [
>                 {
>                    "swaggerObject": "#/definitions/Future«object»",
>                    "message": "Definition is defined but is not used: #/definitions/Future«object»"
>                 }
>              ]
>           }

Comment: Try using an Alternate Type Rule. You can see an example with this [post](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/498#issuecomment-205718626) and the SpringFox [documentation](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#dependencies) Section 2.1.3 #10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your scenario is a slight bit different than the example links I posted in my comment since you are not using the nested **ResponseEntity**. So your implementation would be something more like this:

```
import static springfox.documentation.schema.AlternateTypeRules.newRule;

...

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .alternateTypeRules(
                        newRule(typeResolver.resolve(Future.class),
                                typeResolver.resolve(WildcardType.class)))
                ;
    }
```